# VbScript/ASP Classic good OOP Pattern

Tags: oop, asp-classic, vbscript

Hy all, 
I have to create a website in Classic ASP, and i really want to do a clean design so i will try to put everything in Classes and Models to emulate the ViewModel Pattern.

So can you tell me if this approch of creating objects is good because i will use it everywhere

```
Class User
Public Name
Public Adress
Public Title
Public Text 
Public Rights 'ArrayList of Right objects

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
       Initialize
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
       Dispose
    End Sub

   Private Sub Initialize()
       Name    = ""
       Adress  = ""
       Title   = ""
   Text    = ""
   Set Rights = Server.CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") ' Arraylist .net
   End Sub

   Private Sub Dispose()      
   End Sub

End Class

Class Right

    Public Name

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Initialize
    End Sub

   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
       Dispose
   End Sub

   Private Sub Initialize()
       Name    = ""
   End Sub

   Private Sub Dispose()      
   End Sub

End Class
```

And then i do this for instantiating objects :

```
Dim myUser 
Set myUser = New User

'Do some work

Set myUser = nothing 'Dispose the object
```

Any idea, suggestion or correction is welcome.
Thanks for help.

Comment: this may be a better fit down at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks i added it here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15300/vbscript-asp-classic-good-oop-pattern
But i think i will have more answers here than in codereview

Answer (score 2):

VBScript does not support object instantiation with parameters, but you could add it like this:

```
Public Function [New User](name)
    Set [New User] = New User
    [New User].Name = name
End Function
```

Now you can create a user like:

```
Set myUser = [New User]("Arthur Dent")
```

Usefull when you have mandatory fields you want to set during initialization.

You can also make composites with this technique:

```
Public Function [New PowerUser](name)
    Set [New PowerUser] = New User
    [New PowerUser].Name = name
    Set [New PowerUser].Rights = RightsCollection("PowerUser")
End Function

Public Function [New GuestUser](name)
    Set [New GuestUser] = New User
    [New GuestUser].Name = name
    Set [New GuestUser].Rights = RightsCollection("Guest")
End Function
```

Comment: Clever! But the `[]` notation initially threw me off. I now recognize that the square brackets are used here simply to delimit the function names because they contain a space character. I'd seen the square brackets used in a similar fashion with MS Access queries, but not previously with VBScript...

Answer (score 1):

it don't see a need to create an extra function "Initialize" and "Dispose" and call that from within Class_Initialize() and Class_Terminate() respectively. 
You can just put the code inside the class constructor and destructor.

Secondly, you made your members variables public, if you'd like to make your classic asp work as much object-oriented as possible you should start using getters and setters.
Thus like this:

```
Private m_Name

Public Property Get Name()  
    Name = m_Name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(sName)
    m_Name = sName
End Property
```

With the Rights member variable you're going have more fun :)

Comment: This is a good advise, but there is one error that sneaked in: `Public Property Set` is for objects, `Public Property Let` is for primitives and arrays. In this case you'll need `Public Property Let Name(sName)` because sName is a string.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on this ! I've updated this now.